# JQ - Parsing data

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq

I have something like this in my shell script :

```
 "{ \"ratio\": 32.56351, \"name\": \"Classes\" } { \"ratio\": 9.505888, \"name\": \"Conditionals\" } { \"ratio\": 36.30363, \"name\": \"Files\" } { \"ratio\": 13.349417, \"name\": \"Lines\" } { \"ratio\": 19.908062, \"name\": \"Methods\" } { \"ratio\": 43.75, \"name\": \"Packages\" }"
```

I need to extract something like this out of it :

```
Classes : 32.56351
Conditionals : 9.505888
```

and so on for all the other values and store it in some array or varaible. I am thinking of using the jq json parser : http://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your `json` is not valid. I removed edge double quotes and unescaped the rest of them, like:

```
{ "ratio": 32.56351, "name": "Classes" } { "ratio": 9.505888, "name": "Conditionals" } { "ratio": 36.30363, "name": "File" } { "ratio": 13.349417, "name": "Lines" } { "ratio": 19.908062, "name": "Methods" } { "ratio": 43.75, "name": "Packages" }
```

With it, you can try with string interpolation, like:

```
jq -r '"\(.name): \(.ratio)"' infile
```

That yields:

```
Classes: 32.56351
Conditionals: 9.505888
File: 36.30363
Lines: 13.349417
Methods: 19.908062
Packages: 43.75
```